# how do you escape jsx a component so that it renders as typed instead of computed?

Tags: reactjs

I would like to render a component normally, then for documentation render how it would be need to be typed.

input:

```
<Example date={date} />
<textarea>
  '<Example date={date} />'
</textarea>
```

current output:

```
The example thing today (some date here)
<textarea>
'The example thing today (some date here)'
</textarea>
```

**expected output**:

```
The example thing today (some date here)
<textarea>
  <Example date={date} />
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have the second `<Example>` as a string:

```
<Example date={date} />
<textarea>
  {'<Example date={date} />'}
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go with something like this:

```
<Example date={date} />
<code>
&lt;Example date={date} /&gt;
</code>
```

That is, render a `<code>` element using React, with the contents as a string, using `&lt;` and `&gt;` instead of `<` and `>`.